# Asynchronous approach to using streams with sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, protobuf-net

I've always built my own serializers/deserializers to be able to use BeginReceive/EndReceive with sockets to avoid using one thread per connected socket. It's a quite time consuming task.

I've started to look at protobuf-net and want to used it with async sockets without having to write serialization/deserialization myself. I would prefer if I don't have to use one thread per socket to wrap blocking operations.

Looking at the [quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/QuickStart/3+Sockets.cs?spec=svn212&r=171) they do exactly that (one thread per client). Are there no other way?

My question isn't really about protobuf-net, but about serialization and sockets in general. But examples for protobuf-net is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a basic example. protobuf-net is the *serialization* layer, not the messaging layer. If you have a specific way you want to handle the messaging: go for it. All you need to do is, during your stream processing, buffer up an entire message (perhaps into a `MemoryStream`), then process it via protobuf-net when the data is available.

The difference would be that instead of using the `*WithLengthPrefix` methods directly, you might want to handle to payload-length separately, so that your code knows how much data to buffer before processing.

Comment: The serializer/deserializer methods in Serializer is typed, right?. I don't know which protobuf message I will receive and can therefore not use them, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Marc's answer is correct. Buffering to a "variant" length is not easy, though.

Comment: @jgauffin - there is a mechanism via `Serializer.NonGeneric` that is designed **exactly** for this, with a mechanism to provide the type on-the-fly. There was a recent question with an example of this here on SO.

Comment: excellent. thanks. i'm looking at WCF over TCP with protbuf-net now.